# Iteration not working in custom validation rails for rspec / guard - test not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

So, I have written this custom validation method:

```
    class MedicalDegree < ActiveRecord::Base
      extend Schools

      ...


      validate :validate_awarded_by_based_on_medical_school_table

      ...

       def validate_awarded_by_based_on_medical_school_table
        valid_awarded_by_values = MedicalDegree.medical_schools

        if valid_awarded_by_values.empty?
          error_msg = "the list was empty"
          errors.add(:awarded_by, error_msg)
        end

        unless valid_awarded_by_values.include?(awarded_by)
          error_msg = "is not a valid medical school"
          errors.add(:awarded_by, error_msg)
          errors.add(:awarded_by, valid_awarded_by_values)
        end
      end
    end
```

which uses the function `medical_schools` from my `Schools` module in `models/concerns`:

```
module Schools
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def medical_schools
    schools_list = MedicalSchool.all
    valid_awarded_by_values = []
    schools_list.each do |school|
      valid_awarded_by_values << school.name
    end

    valid_awarded_by_values
  end
end
```

where `MedicalSchool` is the model name which should refer to the `medical_schools` domain table, which contains the names of all valid medical schools.

In the rails console, this method works as it should and so does the validation - however, in rspec, it seems that everything *except for* the `schools_list.each` block runs, as in my test

```
it "is valid with all attributes filled" do
    credential = build(:medical_degree)
    credential.valid?
    expect(credential).to be_valid
  end
```

Rspec returns the error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(credential).to be_valid
       expected #<MedicalDegree id: nil, degree_type: "Osteopathic", awarded_by: "Midwestern University Arizona College of Osteopath...", date_awarded: "2001-01-28", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Awarded by the list was empty, Awarded by is not a valid medical school, Awarded by []
```

I can't figure out why on earth my code works everywhere but inside the rspec test, and why only the .each block fails to execute (so the array of `valid_awarded_by_values` remains empty). I also tried putting the code for the medical_schools method inside the validation method itself, but that also failed to run the `.each` block and only seemed to run the equality statements and `if/unless` statements. I'd really love some help figuring out if my code is the problem or if it's just rspec, and how to fix this!

**EDIT:**

It works just fine if the array itself is defined within the medical_schools method, such as

schools_list = ['school01', 'school02', 'school03'...]

as it was in a previous custom validation I made (then I don't need the iteration block). This whole problem started when I decided to use a domain table to put the values in instead, and to use it for validation.

**EDIT 01:**

I am beginning to believe it's a problem with rspec running my custom validation. In the rails console, my validations work perfectly, but in rspec, anything related to my `MedicalSchool` model comes up empty (`MedicalSchool.pluck(:name)` returned an empty list despite the fact that there are many entries in the database, as did my iteration (which I see now is not the best way of doing this.)

I also was advised that if I just wanted to check a value was in the database, I could just use `MedicalSchool.find_by(awarded_by)` - but despite the fact that the values I'm testing ARE in the database table, in rspec the `MedicalSchool.find_by` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `Schools.medical_schools` is based on the query `MedicalSchool.all` which is something like

```
SELECT * FROM medical_schools
```

so it requires data to be present on the database to then show validate against that. Now, during your test, it might happen that you don't have any medical school recorded on the db, and then no `MedicalDegree` will ever be valid. That's why the `"Awarded by the list was empty"` message is there.

You can create a medical school and then assign the name to the degree before testing for its validity. If you are using [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/) or some other factory helper, you can use that to help you out.

I'd recommend you don't relate things on the database based on names or other arbitrary values, as when one of those values need to be updated you'd need to update the other table too. A better solution would be to have `medical_school_id` and then have a `belongs_to` association as described in [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association). That will also make it easier to use your factory library, at least for factory girl you'll be able to write

```
factory :medical_degree do
  association :medical_school
end
```

Still, when you just want to get a list of a given field of a model, instead of fetching all and then looping through the records, you can use `.pluck` as described [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

```
MedicalSchools.pluck(:name)
```

Comment: The domain table definitely has the entries, so the select * from medical_schools ought to return a list, and did when I tested in the rails console. :) I thought it made sense to use the database to store the list of valid medical schools instead of putting an array within the module method itself (if there were fewer valid schools and I wouldn't have to add any at a future time, I'd just use a nice, simple inclusion validation.

I'll try MedicalSchools.pluck and let you know :)

Comment: Notice that when you use the console you hit the development database. And when running tests you hit the test database, which is good so you don't mess w/ your data. Did you take that into account?

Comment: Hmmmm. I never did think of that! When you seed data, then, does it only seed the development database? Maybe that's the problem, then! :O If so, is it a good idea to seed the test database?

Comment: Correct, seed only applies to the db of the env it was run. Although you can run them by requiring the seed file into your specs, it's not a good idea, and using factories and creating just the data you need for each scenario is the best thing you can do

Comment: That was the problem after all! I never even thought of that! Thanks so much! ^__^